# No se ejecuta evento click

Tags: html5, ajax, vb.net

Estoy tratando de enviar un formulario de una pagina ASPX a AJAX pero no entra a la función del evento `click` del botón en la parte del JavaScript, le he quitado el `runat="server"` al formulario pero me genera error; entonces no se cuál sea el error.

```html
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Index.aspx.vb" Inherits="Index" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#btnEnviar").click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $("#lblIncorrectos").html("Procesando...");
                    var data = {
                        "userid": $("#txtUsuario").val(),
                        "password": $("#txtPassword").val(),
                        "recordarme": $("#chkRecordar").val()
                    };
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Index.aspx/Login",
                        data: data,
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        async: true,
                        success: function (result) {
                            $("#lblIncorrectos").text(result.d);
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            $("#lblIncorrectos").html("Error");
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
        
<form id="form1" role="login" runat="server">
<span>
    <center><img src="img/logo_naranja.gif" class="img-responsive" width="250" height="200" /></center>
</span>
<h3>Nombre de la Empresa</h3>
<div class="form-group">
    <!--<asp:TextBox ID="txtUsuario" runat="server" placeholder="Ingrese su usuario" required class="form-control"></asp:TextBox>-->
    <input type="text" name="txtUsuario" placeholder="Ingrese su usuario" required class="form-control" />
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <!--<asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" placeholder="Ingrese su contraseña" required class="form-control" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>-->
    <input type="password" name="txtPassword" placeholder="Ingrese su contraseña" required class="form-control" />
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <!--<asp:CheckBox ID="chkRecordar" runat="server" value="1" />
                    Recordarme ?-->
 <input type="checkbox" id="chkRecordar" name="remember" value="1" /> Recordarme ?
</div>
<!--<asp:Button ID="btnEnviar" runat="server" Text="Entrar" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" />-->
<button type="submit" id="btnEnviar" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Entrar</button>
</form>
<center><asp:Label ID="lblIncorrectos" runat="server" class="alert alert-danger" rol="alert"></asp:Label></center>           

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: si defines un `alert()` en el click del boton no se muestra ?  el problema es el evento del lado del cliente, o la llamada al servicio mediante ajax en el servidor ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deberias definir el boton como Type="button". O en vez de que el metodo se ejecute al hacer click, que se ejecute en el submit del form1

Cambiar el Tipo:

```
<button type="button" id="btnEnviar" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Entrar</button>`
```

Cambiando El Evento

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#form1").submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#lblIncorrectos").html("Procesando...");
                var data = {
                    "userid": $("#txtUsuario").val(),
                    "password": $("#txtPassword").val(),
                    "recordarme": $("#chkRecordar").val()
                };
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Index.aspx/Login",
                    data: data,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: true,
                    success: function (result) {
                        $("#lblIncorrectos").text(result.d);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        $("#lblIncorrectos").html("Error");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: no es necesario, por que hace preventDefault, lo que evita que se envie el formulario

Answer (score 1):

Creo que te ha faltado incluir la librería jQuery

Intenta agregando esto antes del `<script>` actual y debajo del `<title></title>`.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Lo sospeché desde un principio

Answer (score 1):

Podrias usar el Developer Tools del `browser` (accedes a este con F12) para inspeccionar si hay un error en el codigo javascript.

[Introducción a las herramientas de desarrollo F12](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/gg589512(v=vs.85).aspx)

En la solapa `Console` podras validar si algun error en el codigo cliente evita que se ejecute el evento.